# python for loop for multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code(I know below code is wrong syntax just sharing for understanding requirement) I am using to test multiple for loop.

```
server = ['1']

start = 2
end = 4

for x in range(start,  end + 1) and for y in serverip:
    print x
    print y
```

Requirement.
for loop iterations must not cross  server list  length or range .

```
Input 1 

start = 2
end = 4
server list length = 1 that is server = ['1']

expected output 1:

print 
x = 2
y = 1

Input 2 

start = 2
end = 4
server list length = 2 that is server = ['1','2']

expected output 2:

print
x = 2
y = 1
x = 3
y = 2

Input 3

start = 1
end = 1
server list length = 2 that is server = ['1','2']

expected output 3:

print
x = 1
y = 1
```

Please help.

Comment: That's not valid syntax, but then again that's what you are seeking help with. Please add meaningful inputs and show what the expected output is.

Comment: I _guess_ that you either want `zip` or just a nested loop, but I can only guess, single question is written in an unclear manner.

Comment: This is basic programming. Look for nested loops ;-)

Comment: added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the built-in `zip` function suggested in the comments. `zip` creates a list, or an iterator in python 3, with the iterators “zipped” together. Until one of the iterators runs out.

```
server = ['1']

start = 2
end = 4

for x, y in zip(range(start,  end + 1), server):
    print x
    print y
```

Output:

```
2
1
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip :

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains
>   the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The
>   returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest
>   argument sequence.